# adobe flex problem with Base64Encoder

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, base64

in the following code :

```
var benq:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
benq.encode("force",0,5);
var tmp:String = benq.toString();
```

'tmp' turns out to be an empty string, i.e. with length 0.
why?
how to encode a string using base64encoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that your code isn't working.
I just copied and pasted it into a test app and it returned tmp as 'Zm9yY2U='

Are you doing anything else to the var tmp? if debugging make sure that it has processed the var tmp:String.... line when your checking the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white"
    creationComplete="but1.label = encodeit()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;

        private function encodeit(): String {
            var benq:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
            benq.encode("force",0,5);
            var tmp:String = benq.toString();
            return tmp;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Button 
    id="but1" 
    width="100"
    height="100"
    /></mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flex 3, as it seems to be a new feature? Also try encoding into a bytearray using encodeBytes and using encodeUTFBytes, perhaps these work better.

Online reference is available [from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html), but I guess you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is working.
The code that I posted was different from what I was actually using.
I skipped over the fact that calling toString() for Base64Encoder
clears its internal buffer. So, calling it the next time would return
an empty string.
Sorry for the trouble.